# How to make sure that threads spawned by a Windows Service Timer complete executing after stopping the Windows Service?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, threadpool

I'm building a Windows Service using `System.Timers.Timer`. The tasks computed by the Timer's delegate can take from several seconds to several minutes. I would like to make sure that, when the service is stopped, all delegated threads currently running complete before being disposed.

Here is the code, however it does not do what I expect, as currently running threads never complete if the Windows Service is stopped while they are running.

```
public abstract class AgentServiceBase : ServiceBase
{
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
    private System.Timers.Timer _Timer;
    private string _logPath;
    private const int MAXNUMBEROFTHREADS = 10;
    protected int interval = 25000;
    protected int numberOfAllowedThreads = 2;

    public AgentServiceBase()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this._logPath = (Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType()).CodeBase)).Substring(6).Replace("/", @"\");
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            int.TryParse(args[0], out interval);
        }

        if (args.Length > 1)
        {
            int.TryParse(args[1], out numberOfAllowedThreads);
            if (numberOfAllowedThreads > MAXNUMBEROFTHREADS)
            {
                numberOfAllowedThreads = MAXNUMBEROFTHREADS;
            }
            if (numberOfAllowedThreads == 1)
            {
                numberOfAllowedThreads = 2;
            }
        }

        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(numberOfAllowedThreads, numberOfAllowedThreads);

        this._Timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        this._Timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(PollWrapper);
        this._Timer.Interval = this.interval;
        this._Timer.Enabled = true;

    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        this._Timer.Enabled = false;

        Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

        foreach (Thread t in currentProcess.Threads)
        {
            t.Join();
        }

    }
    /// <summary>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.ServiceName = "Agent Service - Johnhenry";

    }

    private void PollWrapper(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Poll(sender, e);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            string message = this.GetType().FullName + "  - Windows Service Exception\n";
            message += exception.GetNestedExceptionInSingleStringOutput();

            FileHelper.Log(message, this._logPath, "exception", FileHelper.LogFileNameChangeFrequency.DAYLY);
        }
    }

    protected abstract void Poll(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e);
}
```

Many thanks,

Giuseppe

**UPDATE**:

After few different attempts with counting the current process's own threads I eventually settled with a simpler solution which is using a counter of the threads the timer had initiated and are still running. Based on that I call the `Sleep` on the main thread and issue a `RequestAdditionalTime` until all threads have ended.
Following the revised 2 methods:

```
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        this._Timer.Enabled = false;

        while (numberOfRunningThreads > 0)
        {
            this.RequestAdditionalTime(1000);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

    }



    private void PollWrapper(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        numberOfRunningThreads++;

        try
        {
            this.Poll(sender, e);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            string message = this.GetType().FullName + "  - Windows Service Exception\n";
            message += exception.GetNestedExceptionInSingleStringOutput();

            FileHelper.Log(message, this._logPath, "exception", FileHelper.LogFileNameChangeFrequency.DAYLY);
        }
        finally
        {
            numberOfRunningThreads--;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by calling [`RequestAdditionalTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime.aspx) as long as your threads haven't finished the work yet in your implementation of [`OnStop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstop.aspx) inside the loop (before and/or after the call to `Join()`).

**BUT BEWARE** that Windows can get impatient and decide to kill your Windows Service - for example during shutdown...

For more information see the MSDN reference at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.aspx

Comment: Ideally I would like to delay the stopping for no more than the required time. I assume that by using the RequestAdditionalTime I would need to pass a fixed time. Also by adding the RequestAdditionalTime within the loop, will it cumulate the additional time for each pending thread? Thanks.

Comment: yes - it takes a fixed time (in miliseconds) and it adds up so it depends on you having a good estimate of the remaining runtime of your thread(s)... either you call it once before the loop (with a value big enough for all threads) or you call it within the loop with a small value sufficient for one thread to finish)...